# Can I use a single UseStaticFiles middleware for requests in different path in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following directory structure in my root directory:

[image]

I want to use app.useStaticFiles middleware for requests that serve contents inside scripts and styles folder. How can I do that using a single middleware? Is that doable? Do I need to use two separate middlewares here?

Answer (score 2):

The static files middleware serves files under the [web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-files-in-web-root) (`wwwroot`). If you place your structure under that, it will be served automatically by using a path relative to the root, e.g. `myapp.com/scripts/js/1.js`.

Just add this line to your `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

If you for some reason need to serve files from outside web root (probably not advisable), that's possible by specifying [additional options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root).